# Como hacer que un código no se ejecute si no se cumple la condición de un método ?C#

Tags: c#

1. Es una clase hija de otra clase
   2.El codigo se sigue ejecutando aunque le ponga return
2. Quisiera que si no se cumple la condición el código no se siga ejecutando

   ```
    public void _BalanceCuentaOrigen() //Este método es una propiedad heredada
    {

        if (CantidadATransferir > BalanceCuentaOrigen)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: BALANCE INSUFICIENTE!");
            return; //Intente usar el return pero se seguia ejecutando la parte siguente del codigo 

        }
        else if (BalanceCuentaOrigen >= CantidadATransferir)
        {


        }
   ```

Comment: Está muy raro, pone todo el código para poder probarlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No. eso es imposible. el return vuelve a quien lo llamo...

Answer (score 1):

Bien para este caso lo mejor seria usar lo siguiente

```
public String _BalanceCuentaOrigen(){
    if (CantidadATransferir > BalanceCuentaOrigen)
    {
        return "ERROR: BALANCE INSUFICIENTE!";
    }
    else if (BalanceCuentaOrigen >= CantidadATransferir)
    {
        return "OTRO ERROR"
    }
    else{
        return ""
    }
}
```

Asi tendrias todos los caso obtenidos, ya donde llamaste la funcion seria

```
Console.WriteLine(_BalanceCuentaOrigen())
```

Asi deberia de verse

Answer (score 0):

```
public void BalanceCuentaOrigen()
{
    if (CantidadATransferir > BalanceCuentaOrigen)
    {
Console.WriteLine("ERROR: BALANCE INSUFICIENTE!");
    }
    else{
Console.WriteLine("ERROR: LO CONTRARIO!");
    }
}
```

Procura que tus condicionales no lleven redundancia, de todas formas return funciona en metodos void para detener el proceso.